# Add OneNote page using C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am trying to add a page to a Onenote notebook using C#, and the code below.  I can create notebooks and sections in notebooks, so I think the client and scopes are valid, but the last line throws an exception: "Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError.' Any help would be appreciated.

```
private async void createOnenotePage(string sectionId, string htmlString)
    {
        var graphClient = GraphHelper._userClient;

        var onenotePage = new OnenotePage();

        // Convert the HTML string to a byte array
        byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlString);

        onenotePage.Content = contentBytes;

        var response = await graphClient.Me.Onenote.Sections[sectionId].Pages.PostAsync(onenotePage);
        
    }
```

Comment: Add a try-catch block around the `PostAsync` method and examine the exception message

Comment: The exception message is Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: 'Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.'  Thanks for any suggestions for where to look.

Comment: This any help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1192496/odataerror-exception-on-client-credentials-provide

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I can add notebook sections, so I think I have the necessary credentials.  I just can't find help on creating a page in C#.  Graph Explorer has code snippets for Java, but not C#.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same question, the C# SDK does not appear to support this.  This works:

```
 public static async Task<string> createPageAsync3(string token, string sectionId, string htmlContent)
    //Posts a OneNote page.
    {
        // Set up the HttpClient and request header
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Set up the request content as multipart/form-data
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("MyPartBoundary198374"))
        {
            // Add the Presentation HTML content as a form-data part
            var presentationContent = new StringContent(htmlContent);

            presentationContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/html");
            content.Add(presentationContent, "Presentation");

            // Make the POST request to create the OneNote page
            
            var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{sectionId}/pages", content);

            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
```